# sqlite3 error while running gem pristine --all

Tags: sqlite, rubygems

I'm trying to do a `gem pristine --all` and am currently error-ing on the sqlite3 section.
Specifically:

```
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling backup.c
In file included from backup.c:3:
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:51:
./backup.h:7:3: error: unknown type name 'sqlite3_backup'; did you mean 'sqlite3_value'?
  sqlite3_backup *p;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  sqlite3_value
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:1764:20: note: 'sqlite3_value' declared here
typedef struct Mem sqlite3_value;
                   ^
backup.c:63:3: error: unknown type name 'sqlite3_backup'; did you mean 'sqlite3_value'?
  sqlite3_backup *pBackup;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  sqlite3_value
    /usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:1764:20: note: 'sqlite3_value' declared here
typedef struct Mem sqlite3_value;
               ^
```

There are a whole following bunch of warnings, presumably related to these errors. Bottom line also has a reference to `gem_make.out` log file.
Looking in it is basically a retread of the above.

Current environment details... Of which I'm unsure what is useful and what isn't... :)

```
which ruby
/Users/kriston/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
which gem
/Users/kriston/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem
sqlite3 -version
3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22 f5b5a13f7394dc143aa136f1d4faba6839eaa6dc
```

Doing a `gem environment` provides me with this version of gems: `RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24`.

Does anybody have any idea why the sqlite3 compile is failing, and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to install sqlite3 again from scratch using the universal setting.
However, before that I needed to update macports, AND make sure that the 4.3 Xcode dev tools were actually recognized.

So first:
`$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`

and then
`sudo port selfupgrade`

and then finally
`sudo gem install sqlite3 +universal`

After that, running
`gem pristine --all` worked properly!